# Is it possible? PHP

Tags: php, if-statement

[This is my page](http://sile.ga/)

I would make possible that if somebody writes in that imput form a word, PHP redirects him to a page. Is it possible? Can you help me? Thank you alot.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>Magico mondo di Rob</title>
</head>

<body background="img/bg.png">
<div id="paroladiv">
    <form>
        <center>
            <p1> Benvenuto! </p1>
        </center>
        <center>
            <p2 id="parolatext">Inserisci la tua parola magica.</p2>
        </center>
        <p> </p>
        <center>
            <form action="" method="POST">
                <input id="parola" type="text" name="parola"
                       placeholder="Parola va qua."><br>
            </form>
        </center>
</body>
</html>

<?php
if ($_POST['parola'] == google) {
    header("Location: http://google.com");
}
?>
```

Comment: This is something you could do easily with JavaScript. You can easily Google for it I think. There are also many results in italian if you prefer!

Comment: I really don´t know what words should i search on google. Is there any specific function in JavaScript which i can look for?

Comment: `if ($_POST['parola'] == google)` that  will throw you an `undefined constant google` notice. http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: and this isn't a valid HTML markup tag `<p1>`. Nor is `<p2>`.

Comment: You can search, for example for the blur event... And for redirection. Or for a good programmer ;) do you agree @Fred-ii- _amico mio_?

Comment: missing submit button?

Comment: si @LelioFaieta *definitivamente amico mio!*

Comment: @LelioFaieta il "OP" parla la lingua anche!

Comment: @Fred-ii- si è italiano (he is italian as me I guess)

Comment: @Fred-ii- guess I can find you on Facebook too?

Comment: @LelioFaieta *forse* lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two things wrong ..   Your `HEADER` needs to be located at the top of the file to prevent "Headers already sent" error.  --  Plus it's always a good idea to throw a `DIE` in afterward for good measure.

Second, you need to put your `POST` query in quotes as it is a string you are looking for.

Plus as Fred mentioned in comments, you have a stray `FORM` tag

```
<?php
if ( !empty($_POST['parola']) && $_POST['parola'] == 'google') {
    header("Location: http://google.com");
    die();
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
            <title>Magico mondo di Rob</title>
        </head>

            <body background="img/bg.png">
                <div id="paroladiv">
                        <center>
                            <p1> Benvenuto! </p1>
                        </center>
                            <center>
                                <p2 id="parolatext">Inserisci la tua parola magica.</p2>
                            </center>
                        <p> </p>
                        <center>
                            <form action="" method="POST">
                                <input id="parola" type="text" name="parola" placeholder="Parola va qua."><br>
                            </form>
                        </center>   
                </body>             
</html>
```

Comment: forgot the stray `<form>` tag ;-) and best to use `isset()` / `!empty()` && equals to for the POST array

Comment: hahaha!!  Good catch Fred!  -- EDITED

Comment: Well it still doesn´t work.

Comment: Plus, `<p1>` and `<p2>` are not valid HTML markup tags, last I remember. ;-) They probably meant to use `<h1>` and `<h2>`.

Comment: @Jediah well it should. Question is, is that file of your `.php` and are you running this off a webserver with PHP installed, or are you just popping that into your web browser as `file:///file.xxx`? Rather than `http://localhost/file.xxx`? Two different animals here.

Comment: @Jediah Plus, if you're entering `Google` instead of `google`, then that too will fail. In PHP, most of everything is case-sensitive.

Comment: www.sile.ga You can try to see if you find something of wrong in code. 
I put the index.php on my FTP and it doesn´t work. 
And I entered it google. So it shouldn´t be a problem.

Comment: Change _POST to _GET --  your query is ending up in the URL

Comment: @Jediah you didn't get rid of the first `<form>` tag so your form is defaulting to GET. Reload Zak's answer again for the full code.

Comment: Zak solved it. 
But isn´t it the same think? (Nearly)

Comment: Okay Thank you guys.

Comment: @Jediah np  --   :-)  --  Thanks for the added input Fred.

Comment: @Zak You're welcome Zak, *cheers*